# How to: Display ACF [fields] on Custom Post Types Utilising WordPress 'Hooks'?

Tags: custom-post-types, hooks, actions, advanced-custom-fields

**Sub-questions:**

**i) Which files/templates need to be copied to the child theme folder, other than function.php and style.css?**

**ii) What actions/filters/ should be used and where should this code be inserted?**

Apologies, if the following is worded inaccurately, I’m a WP beginner.

I’ve recently installed the Customizr 4.0.8 [as a child theme] on a Localhost, with a view to updating my existing theme. 
I’m attempting to display data from custom fields on the front-end; built using **Advanced Custom Fields Pro (ACF Pro).** 
The data should sit within the main content area of 2x single custom post-types; '**Videos**' and '**Workshops**’

On my current production site http://www.custombike.cc with the 'Workshops' post-type for example, I used single-workshop.php to echo the data from the custom fields and then styled accordingly.

**What I've Tried**

I've copied the code from index.php in the Customizr parent theme and pasted it into the (Child Theme) 'single-workshop.php’ and then inserted the ACF code at various points in the code. 
See PasteBin link ACF Pro Code - Customizr Child Theme https://pastebin.com/TGf7prZg)

From my research, I understand that Customizr uses the index.php to display content using various templates.
I’ve read about Hooks (actions/filters) and understand the concept but I haven't got a clue about; what code, where and how to implement.

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly assign your Custom fields group to the post type you are trying to show them in, then call them in that post types template like you have done already.
For the template part, you need to copy single.php from the Parent theme.

**EDIT:**

For the cutomizr theme you have to make changes in the child theme in the file

> customizr\templates\parts\content\singular\post_content.php

just place

```
    <?php $mymetafield = get_field( "test" ); ?>
    <p><?php echo $mymetafield; ?></p>
```

anywhere you want your metafields to display.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Piyush. I copied the index.php file (as the documentation suggests) to create single-workshop.php and entered the ACF field code but the fields do not show:
The ‘Press Customizr’ theme uses filters and actions within index.php to restrict/display content for pages and posts. 
In terms of single posts, from what I can see it pulls information from the following file: /themes/customizr/templates/parts/content/singular/post_content.php

Comment: When you say assign your Custom field groups to the post type; what does that code look like and where should it be placed?  
Here is the raw index.php code I pasted into the custom post type file (single-workshop.php) https://pastebin.com/HRX29KNV

Comment: Check my edited answer.

Comment: Should I create a workshop_content.php? from post_content.php and then add <?php $mymetafield = $value = get_field( "test" ); ?>
    <p><?php echo $mymetafield; ?></p>                                                    If so where should I add the code? Here's the link to the post_content.php code. https://pastebin.com/qiddGgkG

Comment: What output are you getting if you edit inside that file

Comment: The fields appear using content.php. (https://pastebin.com/qiddGgkG)  but the header and footer don't render correctly. When I use the code in index.php (https://pastebin.com/HRX29KNV) the fields don't appear. :-(

Comment: What do you mean by footer and header don't render properly?...please share code which you have edited in post_content.php and the screenshot of the page

Comment: I haven't edited post_content.php. I've copied the code and created workshop_content.php https://pastebin.com/a2zLNWQT and single-workshop.php https://pastebin.com/aqskvuYj  Screenshot Full page: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rbbp1twjfqdlr1p/workshop-profile.png?dl=0   Screenshot Missing elements: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nh31i5zrzsj7jzo/Missing%20Related%20and%20Comments.png?dl=0